# Wordpress WooCommerce E-Commerce Additional Customer Profile Customization

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building an E-Commerce Website with Wordpress using the WooCommerce plugin.  Trying to add a feature for customers to add a photo to their profile page.  I want this to be manadorty so if the client did not upload photo, I want it to be requested at the process of checkout.

How should I go about this, I been looking all day and can't even find the right file that I am supposed to be editing.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need :

1. Add a form in my-account.php (Check woocommerce_before_my_account hook for this)
2. Create a custom code to save the file in wp_usermeta table ([Check](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) add_user_meta() function ).
3. Check woocommerce hook after_woocommerce_pay to check if there is a photo associated to current user